# Access violation reading location 0x003134d4

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this small exercise that I am trying to finish, but I get an error that I've never seen before. It doesn't even seem logical to me:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0003191a in oop244_a1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003134d4.

Here is the program code:
**The function is at the button (bit_to_ascii), that is where the problem is occuring.** I've tried debugging the program, and it seems that the variable 'clen' gets changed for some reason, to a unreasonably high number (100000+), when its supposed to be 950 characters for that loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LINES 5

/* assignment #1 function prototype */
int bit_to_ascii(const char [ ], char [ ]);

int main( ) {

   const char *core_data[ ] = {
"0", /* should insert the null byte '\0' only */

"01010111 This sequence contains the letter 'W'       " /*  87 = 'W' */
"      r5 0 #! 1 1 gP 0 f66-:] 0 [ } 1 v4t^ 0 1 n>?:77" /* 101 = 'e' */
" junk ^*@&#^% 0110  more junk }{r;,<> 1100         2x" /* 108 = 'l' */
"                  0    1       1     0 0          011" /*  99 = 'c' */
"0  ^%jh  1 ]{) OVR 1 - 0 _! 9 + 1  118Y z(x pM1      " /* 111 = 'o' */
"This next group of 8 should be SKP skipped! 11111111 " /* skipped */
"*&^! 0  1  1  0 1     1 0     128673kjshd:L<    2938 " /* 109 = 'm' */
"      r5 0 #! 1 1 gP 0 f66-:] 0 [ } 1 v4t^ 0 1 n>?:77" /* 101 = 'e' */
"#!/bin/bash 00  1 00 00 0 g^b-ps 6@&^%               " /*  32 = ' ' */
"01010100 This sequence contains the letter 'T'       " /*  84 = 'T' */
"0  ^%jh  1 ]{) OVR 1 - 0 _! 9 + 1  118Y z(x pM1      " /* 111 = 'o' */
"#!/bin/bash 00  1 00 00 0 g^b-ps 6@&^%               " /*  32 = ' ' */
"---repeat--->0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1<------------RPT2--------" /*  79 = 'O' */
"0 1 0 1 0bbavac9872962  000&*************************" /*  80 = 'P' */
"a0b0c1d1e0f0g1h0ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*******************" /*  50 = '2' */
"00fg333                                110100>>>>>>>>" /*  52 = '4' */
"00fg333                                110100>>>>>>>>" /*  52 = '4' */
"                     0000                            ",/*  0 = '\0' */

"00011110 This char should not be inserted!           " /*  30 cntrl */
" 00011111 This char should not be inserted!          " /*  31 cntrl */
"  00100000                                           " /*  32 = ' ' */
"   00100001                                          " /*  33 = '!' */
"    00100010                                         " /*  34 = '"' */
"     00100011                                        " /*  35 = '#' */
"      00100100                                       " /*  36 = '$' */
"       00100101                                      " /*  37 = '%' */
"        00100110                                     " /*  38 = '&' */
"         00100111                                    " /*  39 = ''' */
"          00101000                                   " /*  40 = '(' */
"           00101001                                  " /*  41 = ')' */
"            00101010                                 " /*  42 = '*' */
"             00101011                                " /*  43 = '+' */
"              00101100                               " /*  44 = ',' */
"               00101101                              " /*  45 = '-' */
"                00101110                             " /*  46 = '.' */
"                 00101111                            " /*  47 = '/' */
"                  00110000                           " /*  48 = '0' */
"                   00110001                          " /*  49 = '1' */
"                    00110010                         " /*  50 = '2' */
"                     00110011                        " /*  51 = '3' */
"                      00110100                       " /*  52 = '4' */
"                       00110101                      " /*  53 = '5' */
"                        00110110                     " /*  54 = '6' */
"                         00110111                    " /*  55 = '7' */
"                          00111000                   " /*  56 = '8' */
"                           00111001                  " /*  57 = '9' */
"                            00111010                 " /*  58 = ':' */
"                             00111011                " /*  59 = ';' */
"                              00111100               " /*  60 = '<' */
"                               00111101              " /*  61 = '=' */
"                                00111110             " /*  62 = '>' */
"                                 00111111            " /*  63 = '?' */
"                                  01000000           " /*  64 = '@' */
"                                   00000000          ",/*   0 = '\0'*/

"                                    01000001         " /*  65 = 'A' */
"                                     01000010        " /*  66 = 'B' */
"                                      01000011       " /*  67 = 'C' */
"                                       01000100      " /*  68 = 'D' */
"                                        01000101     " /*  69 = 'E' */
"                                         01000110    " /*  70 = 'F' */
"                                          01000111   " /*  71 = 'G' */
"                                           01001000  " /*  72 = 'H' */
"                                            01001001 " /*  73 = 'I' */
"                                             01001010" /*  74 = 'J' */
"                                            01001011 " /*  75 = 'K' */
"                                           01001100  " /*  76 = 'L' */
"                                          01001101   " /*  77 = 'M' */
"                                         01001110    " /*  78 = 'N' */
"                                        01001111     " /*  79 = 'O' */
"                                       01010000      " /*  80 = 'P' */
"                                      01010001       " /*  81 = 'Q' */
"                                     01010010        " /*  82 = 'R' */
"                                    01010011         " /*  83 = 'S' */
"                                   01010100          " /*  84 = 'T' */
"                                  01010101           " /*  85 = 'U' */
"                                 01010110            " /*  86 = 'V' */
"                                01010111             " /*  87 = 'W' */
"                               01011000              " /*  88 = 'X' */
"                              01011001               " /*  89 = 'Y' */
"                             01011010                " /*  90 = 'Z' */
"                            01011011                 " /*  91 = '[' */
"                           01011100                  " /*  92 = '/' */
"                          01011101                   " /*  93 = ']' */
"                         01011110                    " /*  94 = '^' */
"                        01011111                     " /*  95 = '_' */
"                       01100000                      " /*  96 = '`' */
"                      00000000                       ",/*   0 = '\0'*/

"                     01100001                        " /*  97 = 'a' */
"                    01100010                         " /*  98 = 'b' */
"                   01100011                          " /*  99 = 'c' */
"                  01100100                           " /* 100 = 'd' */
"                 01100101                            " /* 101 = 'e' */
"                01100110                             " /* 102 = 'f' */
"               01100111                              " /* 103 = 'g' */
"              01101000                               " /* 104 = 'h' */
"             01101001                                " /* 105 = 'i' */
"            01101010                                 " /* 106 = 'j' */
"           01101011                                  " /* 107 = 'k' */
"          01101100                                   " /* 108 = 'l' */
"         01101101                                    " /* 109 = 'm' */
"        01101110                                     " /* 110 = 'n' */
"       01101111                                      " /* 111 = 'o' */
"      01110000                                       " /* 112 = 'p' */
"     01110001                                        " /* 113 = 'q' */
"    01110010                                         " /* 114 = 'r' */
"   01110011                                          " /* 115 = 's' */
"  01110100                                           " /* 116 = 't' */
" 01110101                                            " /* 117 = 'u' */
"01110110                                             " /* 118 = 'v' */
" 01110111                                            " /* 119 = 'w' */
"  01111000                                           " /* 120 = 'x' */
"   01111001                                          " /* 121 = 'y' */
"    01111010                                         " /* 122 = 'z' */
"     01111011                                        " /* 123 = '{' */
"      011111RPT10                                    " /* 124 = '|' */
"       01111101                                      " /* 125 = '}' */
"        00000000                                     " /*   0 = '\0'*/
};

   char phrase[41];
   char correct[LINES][41] = {
      "",
      "Welcome To OOP244",
      " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@",
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`",
      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{||||||||||}"
   };

   int rvalues[LINES] = { 1, 18, 34, 33, 39 }, i;
   int valid = 1, rc, err_code;

   for(i=0; i<LINES && valid; i++) {
      rc = bit_to_ascii(core_data[i], phrase);
      if(rc != rvalues[i] || strcmp(phrase, correct[i])) {
     printf("Failed on test... %d\n\n", i+1);
     valid = 0;
      }
      else {
     printf("Passed test %d...\n\n", i+1);
      }
      printf("Your string ----------> '%s'\n", phrase);
      printf("Actual string --------> '%s'\n", correct[i]);
      printf("Your return value ----> %d\n", rc);
      printf("Actual return value --> %d\n", rvalues[i]);
      printf("Press the ENTER key to continue...");
      getchar( );
   }
   if(valid) {
      printf("\nCongratualtions!!! You passed all tests.\n");
      printf("You may hand in your assignment.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("\nYou correctly sequenced %d/5 data blocks...\n", i-1);
      printf("Your program still needs some work!\n");
      printf("Keep at it!\n\n");
   }
   getchar();
   return 0;
}

int bit_to_ascii(const char core[], char data[]) {
    int clen = strlen(core);
    int dlen = strlen(data);
    char bits[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int bit_idx = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int dcount = 0;

    printf("clen: %d\n", clen);

    for (i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
        if (core[i] == '0' || core[i] == '1') {
            bits[bit_idx++] = core[i];

            //printf("bit_idx: %d\n", bit_idx);
            //printf("clen: %d\n", clen);
            //printf("i+1: %d\n", i+1);

            if (bit_idx == 8 || ((i+1) >= clen)) {

                int power = 7;
                double dec = 0.0;
                int j;

                // fill in with zeroes
                for (j = bit_idx; j < 8; j++) {
                    bits[j] = 0;
                }

                // binary to decimal
                for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (bits[j] == '1') {
                        dec += pow((double)2, power--);
                    }
                }

                data[dcount++] = (int)dec;
            }
        }
    }

    return dcount;
}
```

Comment: Try running the code under a debugger - that should take you straight to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it, but probably you have to set `bit_idx` to '0' after reaching `8`.

If not, you will write out of the `bits` array and overwrite the stack. Probably the `clen` variable happens to be just there.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (bit_idx == 8 || ((i+1) >= clen)) {
    ...
    for (j = bit_idx; j < 8; j++) {
        bits[j] = 0;
    }
```

When you reach the for loop `bit_idx` may be 8. Since `8 < 8` is false the loop will continue until `j` wraps around (after millions of iterations). So, at some point, `bits[j]` will most probably access some memory address that you cannot access (or it is invalid) or it will corrupt your program's data/stack. When that happens, your program will be killed (as you are experiencing).

Answer (score 0):

What the hell are you up to in that program?

Oh, well, never mind.  That business with the number getting changed to an unreasonable value makes it sound like the data is getting corrupted.  Now, how would that data get corrupted?  It's being allocated auto, so it's on the stack.  That makes the place to look be in the calling parameters where it's called.

But that's two pointers, not much room for doing something weird there.

What would make strlen produce a very high value?  A string that isn't null terminated.

Conclusion -- look for a case where one of those strings is not getting null terminated.  I'd be tempted to look at `phrase` because it's a constant length -- it's easy to fall off the end. But it could just as easily be that

Oh, and recompile the program with debugging symbols included so you can look at the stack trace in symbolic form.  It'll almost certainly show you the answer.

Comment: It looks random, I know. It's just to test the functionality of the function I am writing in different cases, because the function would be used later on in a different program. 

Thanks for the help though, haha